# for loop do not break in shell script while comparing variable value populated from awk

Tags: shell, loops, awk, break

I am trying to validate data in a file with a pipe delimiter. I still need to work on it for all check conditions. When validation fails, further validation should not happen. Need to skip from a loop. I am unable to determine why the break (or exit) is not working even when the condition is satisfied.

encoding_details variable will have data populated from the configuration table and hold the details of fields for a single file. Based on the configuration, these sets of details will be dynamic for every file.

```
1-memid-ID|2-memfirstname-NAME|3-memlastname-NAME
```

The value represents **column position - column name - column type**

below is the work-in-progress code block. Comments are placed to highlight issues

```
#!/bin/sh

#initiat variables here

retval=0 #this is a variable related with issue

#get configuration details from the table

encrpt_avoid_flag=Y

#extract all files in loop 
#get part of file_name to related configuration
#start validation for each file

#change directory to work on files now
cd  $directy_with_files;

echo "Initiating a process to read files..."
 
extractfilelist=`ls *.txt 2>/dev/null`; 
for file in $extractfilelist
do 
    #now get details of columns to be encrypted for a file 
    encoding_details=`<populated using sqlquery>`   
    
    if [[ -z $encoding_details ]]
    then
        # lets keep this output in a log file - need to work on it
        echo "WARNING: Encoding details not found for file: ${file}"
        echo "Skipping the file from validation scope..." 
    else 
        IFS="|" read -a encoding_column <<< $encoding_details 

        for column in "${!encoding_column[@]}"
        do 
            IFS="-" read -a encoding_column_detail <<< ${encoding_column[$column]}
            column_order=${encoding_column_detail[0]}
            column_name=${encoding_column_detail[1]}
            encoding_type=${encoding_column_detail[2]}
            
            awk -F'|' -v p_column_order="$column_order" -v p_encoding_type="$encoding_type" -v p_encrpt_avoid_flag="$encrpt_avoid_flag" '
            { 
                if ((p_encoding_type == "ID" || p_encoding_type == "NAME") && p_encrpt_avoid_flag == "Y") 
                { 
                    if ($p_column_order != "Blinded" && p_encoding_type == "NAME")
                    {
                        print 1; #this is an error condtion
                        exit;
                    }
                } 
            }' $file | 
            while read retval
            do
                if [ $retval -gt 0 ]
                then
                    echo "ERROR: encryption failed. Please find details below..."
                    echo "column name    : "$column_name 
                    echo "column position: "$column_order
                    echo "file_name      : "$file
                    exit #this exit do not works
                fi
            done
        if [ $retval -gt 0 ]
        then
            break #issue - this break do not work. while printing values inside the if block $retval shows 1 and output get printed as well
        fi
        done #end for column (encoding_column)
    fi #encoding details check end
    if [ $retval -gt 0 ]
    then
        break #issue - this break do not work here as well. while printing values inside the if block $retval shows 1 and output get printed as well
    fi
done #end of file loop
echo "finally : $retval" #and at then end value printed for retval variable is 0? it was 1 when error occoured
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to the smallest possible piece of code that reproduces the problem you're having? Complete with test input, and no placeholders like the SQL query. It's impossible to reproduce otherwise.

Also, you're using `/bin/sh`, but Bashisms such as `[[ ... ]]` in your code – switch to `/usr/bin/env bash` to use Bash.

Comment: See [mcve] for more explanations.

Comment: Sure, I will try to make possible small code blocks in another post. Just tried to give an overall idea if I miss something in other parts like awk. Thanks!

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, especially the part under "Input source selection" about how to read the output of a command in a loop. If you copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about that and other issues with your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all your `break`s depend on the value of `$retval`, which does not exist in the respective scopes. The reason, why `exit` does not seem to work, is that only the `while` loop is exited which exists in a separate process which reads the output of `awk` from `stdin`. Consider the following minimal example:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 1 | 
while read retval
do
    if [ $retval -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "retval is greater than 0"
        exit # this exits only the while loop which is in a separate process
        echo "This does not print"
    fi
done

# retval does not exist in this scope
echo retval: [$retval]
```

This gives you the following output:

```
retval is greater than 0
retval: []
```

As you see, `exit` is exiting the `while` loop and `$retval` does not have any value after the code block in question.